# Sourcing a value from a list box and passing it onto an object on a form

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I would like to take a numerical value found within a list box i have on a form and bring it into a text box on the form itself.  I would like to to this to then use that value as a unique ID number to link to one of the sub forms found on the form.  Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have something like this on one of my forms, I would suggest setting it to a global variable and then using that variable as a control Source.

in VBA create a module and call it something.

```
Public Function Something() As Variant

'Finds the Current Selected value from Form Element
Something = Forms("MainMenu").texbox.Column(1) ' 0 is the First Column

End Function
```

This is what will store your variable. Then you need to call it from your form. If your wanting to pass it to another form i am assuming you have a button or something that calls the other form to open. On the same trigger before any of your other code is ran you need to put:

```
Call Something
```

When you call it, it will set what ever value is in your textbox to that variable.

Once you have this variable stored you would simply put in the control source of the textbox on your other form:

```
=Something()
```

Then when ever your other form is activated it will display what ever ID was stored in the variable.
Just remember if you direct your user away from your form to re-set the variable to nothing.